# VSO Build -- Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Build always fails upon attempt to SYNC, ***Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)***

Repository Type is GIT, 
deployed an agent in local machine,

- Repository Type is Microsoft GIT, hosted by same VSO
- Agent can hook up with Visual Studio Team Services in cloud, i.e., Agent shows up in Default Pool
- Visual Studio can SYNC from local machine where Agent is deployed
- When new build is queued, agent failed upon attempt to sync

Build Definition:

- **Platform**: $(BuildPlatform)
- **Configuration**: $(BuildConfiguration)
- **Visual Studio Version**: 2015
- **MSBuild Architecture**: x64
- **Control Options: enabled**: true

Comment: Can you sync on the Agent? Where is your Repository been managed, VSO or other Git service like GitHub? Can you share the settings of your build definition?

Comment: Thanks so much! I've put in more information, in short: 1. No I cannot SYNC, 2 Hosted in VSO 3. Build Def added above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if "Project Collection Build Service" has "Read" permission to your code repository via following steps:

1. Open your project from Web Portal.
2. Click "Code" to open code panel.
3. Right click on the repository and select "Security" option.
4. Check the permission of "Project Collection Build Service".
   [image]

Make sure "Read" permission is set to "Allow", otherwise you will get a 404 error as following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! It works, after adding one more user, similar to your screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

One additional thing I discovered is Stakeholders cannot access the repos, even if they have Reader or Contributor access by being part of the team. Access levels are controlled at the TFS configuration level under the Access Control tab. Simply remove them from the Stakeholders group and add them to the Basic (default) group, or some other more-specific group you have created.

Comment: This makes sense as Stakeholders are designed for 'clients' to have read-only access.