# Clone repository using TFS fail

Tags: git, git-clone

Trying to clone GIT repository.

Using TFS2013 & VS2015.

Clone on my local machine worked fine. I used this path(http://yourtfsserver.co.uk/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/GitTest) to clone locally but when I try to clone this repository on the server where TFS is installed I get below error.

[image]

When i try to clone I get this error
 **Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)**

I am also getting the same error when I try to build a web project from this repository using TFS builds.

Any idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to use git command to on the build server to see if it works. Such as

```
git clone https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam/_git/FabrikamFiber
```

Also please check if "Project Collection Build Service" and the user account you use to create repository has "Read" permission to your code repository via following steps:

1. Open your project from Web Portal.
2. Click "Code" to open code panel.
3. Right click on the repository and select "Security" option.
4. Check the permission of "Project Collection Build Service".

Make sure "Read" permission is set to "Allow", otherwise you will get a 404 error.

More details please refer this similar question: [VSO Build -- Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007392/vso-build-response-status-code-does-not-indicate-success-404-not-found)

Comment: "Project Collection Build Service" was not part of the security. Adding this group and allowing permissions solved the issue.Thanks.