# TFS 2015 Build, 404 error during GIT sync for build agent

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, devops, tfs-2015

I have TFS 2015, my issue just appeared after adding more teams into my team project with explicit permissions. So when I start the build eather using CI or manually it displays

> Syncing repository: ProjectName (Git)
>
> Starting fetch...
>
> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
>
> Prepare repository failed with exception.

I've added the read permission to my collection build service account but with no luck.

If there is no solution to this problem, is there any way to reset all permissions to default

Comment: Did you verify the members are in stakeholder? Acc to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723291/7073340) answer if the members are added as a stakeholders then this error will occur

Comment: Also try changing another account which have the read permission as the build agent service account, then try it again.

Comment: @Jayendran I added the account used by the build agent as basic, and it was me who made request the queue of the build(Basic user & Administrator), but with no luck. I've followed the answer you've shared before posting the question but with no luck.

Comment: @Andy Li-MSFT what do you mean by changing account

Comment: @Yazid Change the build agent service account (the account which you specified during deploy the agent).

Comment: @Andy Li-MSFT yes sure I will try that and let you know, just to make sure that i will follow you. I will re configure the build agent with a new account that have the collection build service read permission

Comment: @Andy Li-MSFT I've change the account used by the build agent but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution was approximately similar to the [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007392/vso-build-response-status-code-does-not-indicate-success-404-not-found/40723291#34034453) except in my case I needed to add

> Project Collection Build Service with read Permission Allowed

Which means that even if you have the inherited permission from the collection or the team project, you must add the additional TFS group to the project permissions

Steps that need to be followed are:

1- Follow steps shared in the link
2- Add Project Collection Build Service with read Permission Allowed

Comment: The link which you shared that also showed the `project collection build service with read permission` which means the link which I shared is already solved your problem if you read the answer properly.

Comment: Yes you are right, after reading the comment of the solution that has been marked correct.